# Python Requests + Azure VM

Tags: python, django, azure, request, ckan

I'm using python requests library to talk between two of my apps (django and ckan) inside Azure VM (clean ubuntu 12.04).

And very wired bug appears. It seems like `request.post` sent successfully, but on the middle of my code running I got `504 request timeout`.

Apache2, Nginx and Gunicorn (only timeout appears) logs are clean. My CKAN app throws same error but with different ports:

CKAN error example 1:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53555)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/httpserver.py", line 1068, in process_request_in_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

CKAN error example 2:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53344)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/httpserver.py", line 1068, in process_request_in_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

As you can see port Is always different. One of my thoughts -- Azure has all ports closed unless you specify which one you want to open.

I have same codebase working alright locally.

Comment: Yes, by default, Azure linux VMs disable all ports except 22 to prevent inbound requests from internet. you can try to specify your Django app's port and configure the endpoint of the other VM with ckan.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure linux VMs disable all ports except 22 to prevent inbound requests from internet. you can try to specify your Django app's port and configure the endpoint of the other VM with ckan.

Also, you can refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-python-django-web-app-linux.md to deploy your django app on apache and bind it on 80 port on your VM.